# HTTP Responses Flipped

Tags: angular

I have an interesting issue that I can't seem to resolve. My application uses HTTP calls to various endpoints and the majority of them work with no issues. There is one in particular that is causing me a headache and is probably the simplest of them all.

I have a service which contains a function that has a return value that looks like the following.

```js
 return this._http.post(this.baseEndPoint + this.uri, postc, options)
        .map(res => res.json());
```

Which, to me, is pretty standard. What's strange is that on any error response/code, the code in my success/complete function is being executed and on any successful response, the code in my error function is being executed. The responses from the API come back as a 404 and 204 so I would expect they be caught accordingly.

```js
this._service.function(param, param1)
  .subscribe(
    error => {
      console.log(error);
    },
    () => {
      console.log('lol wut');
    }
  );
```

There's nothing special here at all. Also, I'm noticing that my requests are making two network calls, one being initiated by polyfills which shows successful with a status of 200 but then it's followed by another call with a status of 404 triggered by "other."

So, my questions are — why are these reversed? How do I resolve that and allow them to be caught in appropriate place? Why are there two calls being made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing two network requests because of Request OPTIONS , Angular makes a preflight HTTP OPTIONS request because of cross origin nature of request.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS.
Also , your callbacks are written in wrong order

```
this._service.function(param, param1)
        .subscribe(
            error => { // DONT CONFUSE with the name error, it can be any //name
                console.log(error);
            },
            () => {
                console.log('lol wut');
            }
        );
```

Here , the first argument method is called upon success , 2nd on error and third is info I think.
Actual callbacks should be

```
this._service.function(param, param1)
        .subscribe(
           data=>{
                    console.log("status code is ",data.status);},
            error => {
                console.log(error);
            },
            () => {
                console.log('lol wut');
            }

        );
```

Or as per your need.

Comment: Interesting, I guess I just assumed that order wasn't an issue and thought that error worked by catching the type of response. I'll try this out and see what's up.

Comment: Here is the definition of subscribe from Observable library
------------------
subscribe(next?: (value: T) => void, error?: (error: any) => void, complete?: () => void): Subscription;
----------------------

Comment: Ah, perfect. Thank you much!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you are seeing two network requests, but based on your argument names, I think you have your callbacks reversed? `subscribe`'s first argument can be a function that will execute on `next` notifications on a stream, the second argument will be invoked on `error` notifications. The third is for completion notifications.

```
this._service.function(param, param1).subscribe( onNext, onError, onComplete );
```

If order is a problem, you can also provide an object to subscribe which implements the observer interface, like so:

```
this._service.function(param, param1).subscribe({
  next: x => console.log( x ),
  error: x => console.error( x ),
  complete: () => console.info( 'done!' ),
});
```